# Summarizing an arbitrary # of columns in a data frame using my own function in R

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I am looking for a way to summarize a large flat table of experimental results in R. The summarization is *not* straightforward since I need to summarize an arbitrary # of columns (cannot hardcode the columns beforehand) and use an arbitrarily defined summary function.

As an example say I have the following flat table, `my_table`

```
my_table
   id_1 id_2 rep_id value_1 value_2
1     a    1      1     0.0     0.0
2     a    1      2     0.2     0.2
3     a    1      3     0.3     0.3
4     a    1      4     0.4     0.4
5     a    1      5     0.1     0.1
6     a    2      1     0.5     0.0
7     a    2      2     1.5     1.5
8     a    2      3     2.5     2.5
9     a    2      4     3.5     3.5
10    a    2      5     4.5     4.5
```

I would summarize `my_table` into a table such as:

```
> summary_table
  id_1 id_2 value_1.min value_1.max value_1.mean_plus_sd value_2.min value_2.max value_2.mean_plus_sd
1    a    1         0.0         0.4            0.3581139           0         0.4            0.3581139
2    a    2         0.5         4.5            4.0811388           0         4.5            4.1464249
```

The summarization is complicated since I would like to:

1. Specify the variables to group by, e.g. `key_fields = c("id_1","id_2")`
2. Specify the columns to summarize, e.g. `fields_to_summarize = c("value_1","value_2")`
3. Use my own summarizing function (that also names the new columns)

Here is the code that I am currently using to do all 3 of these things. This is nice, but it's also really inefficient. Any improvements would be really appreciated:

```
library(plyr)

# create table
my_table = data.frame("id_1"  = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a")
                    ,"id_2" = c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2")
                    ,"rep_id" = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
                    ,"value_1"= c(0.0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5)
                    ,"value_2"= c(0.0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.0,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5)
    )

# specify columns to group by / summarize over
key_fields = c("id_1","id_2")
fields_to_summarize = c("value_1","value_2")

# create summary_table
counter = 1;
for (fname in fields_to_summarize){

  summary_function = function(D) data.frame(setNames(list(min(D[[fname]]),
                                                          max(D[[fname]]),
                                                          mean(D[[fname]])+sd(D[[fname]])),
                                                     paste(fname,c("min",
                                                                   "max",
                                                                   "mean_plus_sd"),
                                                           sep=".")
  ))

  tmp = ddply(.data = df, 
                 .variable = key_fields,
                 function(D) summary_function(D))

  if (counter == 1){
    summary_table = tmp;
  } else {
    summary_table = join(x=summary_table,y=tmp,by=key_fields,type="left", match="all")
  }
  counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a classic opportunity to use `aggregate`. Please do some searching on SO for the many worked examples to basically identical questions (and answers).

Comment: @Arun, do you think this could be somehow nicely answered using `data.table`? My best attempt was `setDT(my_table)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) c(min(x), max(x), mean(x) + sd(x))), by = key_fields, .SDcols = fields_to_summarize]`, but this gives a long format and you can't tell which value represents what

Comment: @Arun, that's nice, though it still lacks automatic naming

Answer (score 4):

not the final solution, but perhaps a good start with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

mean_plus_sd <- function(x) mean(x) + sd(x)
key_fields = c("id_1","id_2")

my_table %>%
  group_by_(.dots = key_fields) %>%
  summarise_each_(funs(min,max,mean_plus_sd), fields_to_summarize)
```

Comment: Yes! This is *very* close to what I was looking for. The only thing is that this automatically appends the summarized field names with an underscore + the function name. Is there some way to make it use a "." instead of a "_" (e.g. value_1.min instead of value_1_min)?

Comment: @docendodiscimus thank you for the completion. @BerkU. you could replace the last _ with a . but it seems "dirty" for me, there might be better solutions `names(my_table) <- str_replace(names(my_table),"_([^_]*)$",".\\1")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's are two quick functions you could define. First is using base R approach, second is using a possible `data.table` approach

```
My_func <- function(data, fields_to_summarize, key_fields){
                    aggregate(data[fields_to_summarize], 
                     data[key_fields], 
                     function(x) c(min = min(x), 
                                  max = max(x),
                                  mean_plus_sd = mean(x) + sd(x)))
}

My_func2 <- function(data, fields_to_summarize, key_fields){
                as.data.table(data)[, lapply(.SD, 
                                      function(x) c(min(x), max(x), mean(x) + sd(x))), 
                key_fields, 
                .SDcols = fields_to_summarize][, 
                      Funs := c("min", "max", "mean_plus_sd")][]
}
```

Testing first funciton

```
key_fields = c("id_1","id_2")
fields_to_summarize = c("value_1","value_2")

My_func(my_table, fields_to_summarize, key_fields)
#   id_1 id_2 value_1.min value_1.max value_1.mean_plus_sd value_2.min value_2.max value_2.mean_plus_sd
# 1    a    1   0.0000000   0.4000000            0.3581139   0.0000000   0.4000000            0.3581139
# 2    a    2   0.5000000   4.5000000            4.0811388   0.0000000   4.5000000            4.1464249
```

Testing second function

```
library(data.table)
My_func2(my_table, fields_to_summarize, key_fields)

#    id_1 id_2   value_1   value_2         Funs
# 1:    a    1 0.0000000 0.0000000          min
# 2:    a    1 0.4000000 0.4000000          max
# 3:    a    1 0.3581139 0.3581139 mean_plus_sd
# 4:    a    2 0.5000000 0.0000000          min
# 5:    a    2 4.5000000 4.5000000          max
# 6:    a    2 4.0811388 4.1464249 mean_plus_sd
```

Comment: Quick question: is a data.table solution faster than dplyr? I've seen it mentioned several times in these forums.

Comment: I don't know, you could probably test on your data set.